# Can multiple milestones be placed on the same line in pgfgantt?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I'm writing a funding proposal and have used pgfgantt to make a chart of timescales for personnel hiring and work package developments, but I would also like to be able to indicate the plans for timing of several group meetings, etc. through the period of the project.

I would like these to appear in the way that pgfgantt displays milestones, i.e. points at a single time rather than bars indicating a time range, but there is no reason that they should appear on separate rows in the chart.

In the documentation and all examples, I only see how to mark milestones one-per-row. Is there a way to mark several milestones on a single labelled ("Meetings") row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if that answers your question, since you have neither included a minimum example nor a picture of how your desired output should look like. However here's a possible way on how to place multiple milestones on one line:

The function `\ganttmilestone` accepts two arguments aswell as options:

```
\ganttmilestone[ options ]{ label }{ tss }
```

You can place multiple "meeting" symbols on the same row by simply calling `\ganttmilestone{}{tss}` twice without `\\` and by leaving the `{ label }` field empty:

As an example:

```
 \begin{ganttchart}[hgrid, vgrid]{1}{25}\
    \gantttitle{2016}{25} \\
    \gantttitlelist{6,...,30}{1} \\
    \ganttgroup{Start}{1}{1} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
    \ganttlinkedbar{Task 2}{3}{7}
    \ganttnewline
    \ganttmilestone{Meetings}{7}
    \ganttmilestone{}{18}
    \ganttmilestone{}{22}
    \ganttnewline
    \ganttbar{Final Task}{15}{18}
\end{ganttchart}
```

Which gives the following output:

[image: Multiple Milestones on one line]